# Why are 2 Terminal windows opening with NSAppleScript?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

If no Terminal app is open, the following code opens TWO Terminal windows. Why is it doing this? I only want one window to open.

If only one Terminal window is open, then the following code opens only ONE additional window.

```
NSAppleScript* terminal = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                           [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"tell application \"Terminal\"\n"
                                @"    activate\n"
                                @"    do script \"echo %@\"\n"
                                @"    tell the front window\n"
                                @"    set title displays shell path to false\n"
                                @"    set title displays custom title to true\n"
                                @"    set custom title to \"My session! %@\"\n"
                                @"    end tell\n"
                                @"end tell", name, name]];

[terminal executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Comment: When you say two Terminal "apps", do you mean two Terminal windows or two actual instances of the application?

Comment: two windows - thanks for the pickup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do script` command, as you've written it, will always run in a new window. If you'd like it to run in a specific window, use the following format: `do script (...) in (window...)`. Terminal's `in` syntax can also handle running scripts in tabs.

For instance, if you'd like to run a script in the frontmost window, you can write `do script "echo Hello, world!" in front window`.

---

**Edit:** To follow up, if you'd like to always run the script in a window (create a new one if none are open), you can use the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    if length of (get every window) is 0 then
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to click menu item "New Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
    end if
    do script "echo Hello, world!" in front window
end tell
```

Of course, you'll need to correctly escape it in an `NSArray`, but that I'm sure you can do.

Comment: I do want my `echo` command to always run in a new window. The problem is when there are no windows open, my script will open two windows instead of one.

Comment: Nice work! I went about it another way and did a `if it is running then`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to compare with:

```
tell application "Terminal"
  if it is running then
      do script "echo %@"
  else
      activate
      do script "echo %@" in front window
  end if
  tell the front window
      set title displays shell path to false
      set title displays custom title to true
      set custom title to "My Terminal!"
  end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I just realised my solution doesn't work if Terminal is running without any windows open

Comment: Yeah. `activate` will ensure it's running, and in the foreground (replacing `if it is running`), and the rest will ensure there's at least 1 window open to work in.